# Database Showing Comments as Deleted

Tags: database

Hello i have recently changed domains and ..well it cant be related can it? anyhow all my old comments are not showing. When i went into the database via phpmyadmin i notice that the deleted coloum which should say 0 has 1 in there for all the old comments.

also i note that the bundle coloum (sorry table?) is showing 'comment_node_forumpost' not 'comment_node_post' which is my current content type.

sorry im in field_data_comment_body.

I dont want to do anything wrong here but i have been trying (to do something right)

Can anyone suggest a query that i could run that will reset all my deleted table to 0 and my comment_node_forumpost to comment_node_post?

Thanks

Comment: ps i should mention that the comments are still showing in the comment body value

Comment: i done a query UPDATE field_data_comment_body SET deleted = '0' which seem to have worked. I was just about to do this...UPDATE field_data_comment_body SET bundle = 'comment_node_post' when i suddenly realised i only want to change any instances of comment_node_forumpost to comment_node_post. Not my video types etc. Anyone help a man out? thanks